# Get Front and Back Camera Megapixels in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hardware

Im working on a flutter app that gets software and hardware details of a phone.I m having trouble in how to get megapixels of camera.Is there any flutter package for it that im missing?

I tried using https://pub.dev/packages/camera but unable to get anything.I saw a video that calculates megapixels after taking a picture but i dont want the camera to be opened i just want the value of megapixels.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this. package to get camera info

> camera_info: ^1.0.3

import this

> import 'package:camera_info/camera_info.dart';
> import'package:camera_info/model/camera_info.dart';

and do this to get camera megapixels

```
void getCameraInfo() async {
      List<CameraInfo> cameras = await CameraInfo.getCameraInfo();
    
      for (CameraInfo camera in cameras) {
        print('Camera ID: ${camera.cameraId}');
        print('Camera Megapixels: ${camera.megapixels}');
      }
    }
```

Comment: This package is not available on flutter pub.dev